# Submit form in iframe strange results

Tags: forms, iframe

I have this test page which has an iframe within. If I search for something (i.e. PR, IT) on parent page form, it triggers results in iframe but with one small problem, we don't have correct options on the left column, which is filtering options (nr. of jobs resulted,city selection,etc). If I search on iframe itself for the same thing, results comes correct and we can filter results. I don't understand what I did wrong.

This is the parent page form that triggers results in iframe :

```
<form id="SearchForm" action="http://mysite.com/search-results-jobs/" target="my-iframe"   method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="listing_type[equal]" value="Job" />
            <label><strong>What?</strong>
<em>
<input type="text" value="job title, keywords or company name" 
onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='job title, keywords or company name'" 
onFocus="if(this.value =='job title, keywords or company name' ) this.value=''" name="keywords   [all_words]" />

</em></label>




            <label><strong class="color">Where?</strong><b><input      type="text" value="city, state or zip code"  
onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='city, state or zip code'" onFocus="if(this.value =='city, state or zip code' ) this.value=''" name="City[all_words]" /></b></label>


            <a href="#" class="SearchForm-link" onclick="one(); two();   three(); four();">Search</a>
        <input type="submit" id="btn-search" class="button"  value="Cauta"/></form>
```